# Extract a substring in Ruby using a regular expression

Tags: ruby, logstash

How can I extract a substring from within a string as field name in Ruby?

output Example:

```
A-field:name.23.134 => 6

ruby {
        code => "

             if key =~ /^A-field:[A-Za-z]+/ then
                     #how to get the match pattern ?and the field value ?                     

               end


}
```

how to get the match pattern as field anme and the field value ,
after filter ,it's will be looks like

A-field:name  => 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that will retrieve the field name and the value separately:

```
text = "A-field:name.23.134 => 6"
matches = text.match(/([^:]+:[^=\.\s]+)(\.\d+)*\s*=>\s*(.+)/)
puts "Field: #{matches[1]}"
puts "Value: #{matches[3]}"
puts "#{matches[1]} => #{matches[3]}"
```

The output of this is:

```
Field: A-field:name
Value: 6
A-field:name => 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, but with the assumption as below,
1. The string are in form of (field1).numbers_to_ignore => number_to_capture

you try this.

```
string = "A-field:name.23.134 => 6"
matchdata = string.match /(?<field1>[^.]*).*(?<field2>=>.*)/
matchData[1]
>> "A-field:name" # same result as matchData["field1"]
matchData[2]
>> "=> 6"  # same result as matchData["field2"]
```

or in simpler form, you could use regex like this

```
/([^.]*).*(=>.*)/
```

which still gives same output except the field name.

First parenthesis captures all characters except a dot, before a '=>' character. Then, the second parenthesis captures all characters starting with '=>'.

Hope this helps.